# Xamarin.android How to get control name

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I have added a control (TextView) to a layout in the main Activity. I want to get the original

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/currentLenguajeLabel"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/TextViewCurrentLenguajeLabel" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in the code I get the control like this:

```
TextView myControl = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.TextViewCurrentLenguajeLabel);
```

How can I get the name of the control (**TextViewCurrentLenguajeLabel**)?

I need it to send it to a translation function

I know that that is the name, but I need to send the name to a method. I want to avoid to do something like this

```
myControl.Text = localizationMethod(“TextViewCurrentLenguajeLabel”);
```

I want to do something like this

```
myControl.Text = localizationMethod(myControl.GetControlName());
```

Comment: That IS the name of the TextView - are you perhaps meaning how do you get the Text of the TextView?

Comment: I know that that is the name, but I need to send the name to a method I want to avoid to do something like this 
`myControl.tText = localizationMethod(“TextViewCurrentLenguajeLabel”);`

I want to do something like this
`myControl.tText = localizationMethod(myControl.GetControlName());`

Comment: I see what you mean, or, at least I think I see. I'll try to answer it below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method [`Android.Content.Res.Resources.GetResourceName`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Content.Res.Resources.GetResourceName/p/System.Int32/) could help you to do this. You could define the following extension method

```
public static class ViewExtensions
{
    public static string GetControlName(this View view)
    {
        string controlName = "";
        if (view.Id > 0)
        {
            string fullResourceName = Application.Context.Resources.GetResourceName(view.Id)
            controlName = fullResourceName.Split('/')[1];
        }
        return controlName;
    }
}
```

And use it like this

```
var controlName = myControl.GetControlName();
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this, try the following:

```
void localizationMethod(TextView tv)
{
  tv.Text = "Some New Text";
}
```

Then to use it, get the TextView via the normal

```
TextView myControl = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.TextViewCurrentLenguajeLabel);
```

And then calling `localizationMethod(myControl);`

This will give the localizationMethod access to the control and you can then work with it in the method as you wish.